# Click on button to store localstorage array and display the same as list view in ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, local-storage

In my ionic app, i want to store value in localstorage as an array in the same key and not replace the value.

I am using the below query, but not able to save the array.

Every time i click, it is replacing the value.

my home.ts has below query.

```
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date +' '+time;   

var items = [];
items.push(dateTime);
localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(items));
```

Please suggest where i am doing mistake.

Output in localstorage is as below. For every click, it is replacing the value.

```
**Key**                        **Value**
 item                   ["2020-8-29 12:6:50"]
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand, what you want to achieve?, and, what is the problem?

Comment: I have updated the query. Please see if that help. Actually i want to save an array in localstorage instead of replacing existing value in the same key

Comment: I think, he is expecting addItem() functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with the below solution.

```
var time= "10"; 
localStorage.setItem('datatemp', time);
            const task = localStorage.getItem('datatemp');            
            let data;
            if(localStorage.getItem('data') === null) {
              data= [];
            } else {
              data= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
            }
            data.push(task);
            localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

In local storage it will save data as below:

```
data = ["10","10"...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the new value or entries to the stored value. You can do this in three simple steps:

1. retrieve stored array of values,
2. concatenate or push the new value (this depends on desire result),
3. store the result array of 2)

Following your code, it would be something like this,

```
const storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage["datearray"]); // 1
const newValue = storedValue.push(dateTime); // 2 - with the result will be [[v1]..[vn]]
localStorage["datearray"] = JSON.stringify(newValue); // 3
```

BTW, If you are going to use a variable `localStorage` to keep the values in memory, you could just keep the arrays. Then at the start of the application you initialize this variable with the stored array value, and just save it on close or when you need it. At the moment of get or set the values of the array you transform the string to array and viceversa.

UPDATE

Like I mention, the problem is that you are not extending the result you are replacing it. Let me try to explain it again with a function to add a new value to a stored array.

```
function addToStoredArray(key, item, storage) {
  // 1.1) retrieve stored array
  storage.get(key)
    .then(val => {
      // 1.2) convert to array
      const arr = JSON.parse(val);
      // 2) add new item to array
      arr.push(item);
      // 3)store again the array
      storage.set(key, JSON.stringify(arr));
    });
}
```

Now, following your code, you only need to invoque the funcion like this,

```
// create new value
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date +' '+time;
// add it to the stored array   
addToStoredArray("item", JSON.stringify(items), localStorage);
```

Hope it is a bit more clear.

Comment: I followed, but it is throwing error "storedValue.push is not a function".                              
 My code is as below :                                                                 
             `localStorage["datearray"] = JSON.stringify(dateTime);
              var storedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage["datearray"]);1
              var newValue = storedValue.push(dateTime); 
              localStorage["datearray"] = JSON.stringify(newValue);`

Comment: I have updated the original query with few information.